# Strongloop REST Connector - connecting to non-REST remote resources

Tags: rest, loopbackjs, strongloop

We have an existing web application which has an API not based on REST. We'd like to put a REST API in front of it, using Strongloop, however, getting lost in the documentation and not sure if this can be achieved.

Example:

Want to configure an endpoint in Strongloop which looks like;

**localhost:3000/api/DataObject/Orders?StartDate=01/01/2016&EndDate=31/01/2016**

A GET on this end point should service the request from our existing web application, where the URL would like;

**localhost:4000/wh?Page=ObjectBuilder&Name=Orders&StartDate=01/01/2016&EndDate=31/01/2016**

i.e. take Orders from the API request and insert into the remote URL, along with the remaining parameters.

I could code this using express.js, but was wondering if this is possible using configuration in Strongloop?

Thanks!

Comment: You *can* do this with LoopBack, but you end up doing a lot of work yourself. because you basically have to rewrite the `find`, `findById`, `save`, `destroy`, etc methods to match your endpoints. However, the REST connector doesn't just have to connect to a proper "REST" API, it can connect to any URL-based API. I'll see if I can work up an example using the URL format you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to use the [built-in REST connector](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/REST+connector) even though your legacy API is not REST per se (although you don't get all the benefits of the built-in mapping to `find`, `create`, `destroy`, etc). The connector simply translates URLs into model methods. That said, I think you do need to have the old API spit out JSON... does it do that? If not, then you basically just have to write a full translator.

*This is not working code*, but might help you get part of the way there.

In your `server/datasources.json` file:

```
"old-service": {
    "name": "old-service",
    "connector": "rest",
    "operations": [{
        "template": {
            "method": "GET",
            "url": "http://localhost:4000/wh",
            "headers": {
                // whatever you might need to send...
            },
            "query": {
                "Page": "ObjectBuilder",
                "Name": "{name}",
                "StartDate": "{start}",
                "EndDate": "{end}"
            },
            "responsePath": "$.results.theObject" // be sure to custom ize this
        },
        "functions": {
            "buildObject": ["name", "start", "end"]
        }
    }]
}
```

In your `server/model-config.json` be sure too map your `DataObject` model to this datasource:

```
{
  // ...
  "DataObject": {
    "public": true,
    "dataSource": "old-service"
  },
}
```

And in your model itself (`common/models/DataObject.js`) you can now call the `buildObject()` method:

```
DataObject.buildObject('Order', '01/01/2016', '31/01/2016', function(err, result, response) {
  if (err) { ... }
  // otherwise look at the result or response...
});
```

Now that you can call this method, you could put it into a [remoteMethod](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Remote+methods) or even [override the default `find` method](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Customizing+models#Customizingmodels-Changetheimplementationofbuilt-inmethods) for this model.

Good luck, but in many of these cases you simply have to write the "conversion" code yourself. Might be easier to rewrite the API from scratch. ;)